# Appending and searching in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, nested-lists, dynamic-arrays

So my problem is that I want to append a name of something to an array, and a count.

```
test_array = []
test_array.append(['apples', 2])
test_array.append(['oranges', 5])
test_array.append(['bananas', 1])

print(*test_array)

['apples', 2]
['oranges', 5]
['bananas', 1]
```

Now I would like to search my 2d array by the name of the thing I am counting and add 1 to the second column

```
test_array['oranges'][1] = test_array['oranges'][1]+1
```

I would test for the existence of the item before adding 1 to the second column

```
if test_array['string'] != None:
    test_array.append['string', ]
```

I am not sure if this is possible, or if I will just need to search the entire first column of the array for the item before appending to the list.  I am going to be doing this for 37,731,481 items so I would need a way to search strings that would hopefully not be quadratic in run time, so I would probably just sort my list by the strings and do a binary search.

Comment: I think you'll need to search the entire first column of the array before appending. It seems like maybe a dictionary would be a better data structure for your use case?: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a mapping instead of the nested lists, most preferably a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object. The items will be the keys and their counts will be values. Then searching for a key can be done in constant time - *O*(1).

```
from collections import Counter

dct = Counter()
dct['apples'] = 2
dct['oranges'] = 5
dct['bananas'] = 1
print dct
# Counter({'oranges': 5, 'apples': 2, 'bananas': 1})
```

And you won't need to test for key existence to add/update values:

```
# updating a key (which is not in the counter)
dct['mango'] += 3
print dct
# Counter({'oranges': 5, 'apples': 2, 'mango': 3, 'bananas': 1})
```

This is so because `collections.Counter` objects unlike vanilla dicts always return zero for missing keys rather than raise a *KeyError*.

In case you need to manage negative counts, a `Counter` object will not be the best choice. You could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object instead making the *default_factory* the `int` function:

```
from collections import defaultdict:

dct = defaultdict(int)
...
```

Works the same way as the `Counter` except negative counts are now properly handled.